# Error installing gt package in R studio on a Mac

Tags: r, install.packages, error-messages-for

When I attempt to install the package gt I'm met with the following error message

`> install.packages("gt") Error in install.packages : error reading from connection`

Is there a way I can install the package gt in R Studio on a Mac?

Comment: Have you tried installing from github? (e.g. `devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jared_mamrot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12957340/jared-mamrot) suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68284557/error-installing-gt-package-in-r-studio-on-a-mac/68284969#comment120682825_68284557), the solution was:

```
devtools::install_github(rstudio/gt)
```